# Third Party Google Cookies on Google OAuth Login

Tags: web, cookies, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm using Google OAuth for login on my website and I'm testing It on localhost. I noticed that Google added some 3rd party cookies on my website after signing in. I guess Google OAuth also uses one of these cookies because when I attempt to login again, I skip the process of selecting an account to sign into and instead, I get directly sent to my redirect URL (my home page). My question is, what are these cookies?

[image: image of cookies] (imgur)

Can Someone explain to me what the purpose of each of these cookies are or provide a resource where I can learn about each specific one? Also, are they needed or should I delete them (I don't want google tracking anything on my website unless its super helpful)? Should I create my own cookies for auth?